# Headless in Windows 7 for Ruby in Watir?

Tags: ruby, watir, headless

I am new here. Is there any way to use headless in windows? I tried but it says :

> :/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/headless-1.0.1/lib/headless/cli_util.rb:4:in ``': No such file or directory - which Xvfb (Errno::ENOENT)

Please help...

Answer (score 1):

Headless Tests in "WINDOWS7" using `WATIR`? You can use `phantomjs` which is super easy to configure.
Follow these easy steps:

1. Download `phantomjs` from [here](http://phantomjs.org/download.html)
2. Extract to desired folder, once extracted you just need `phantomjs.exe`
3. Now where ever you instantiating the browser, use it like this:

   ```
   phantom_dir = "location of phantomjs.exe"
   ENV['PATH'] = "#{ENV['PATH']}#{File::PATH_SEPARATOR}#{ghost_dir}"
   browser = Watir::Browser.new :"phantomjs"
   ```

To run headless on other OS follow easy steps [here](https://pushprajsingh05.wordpress.com/2015/01/11/run-headless-tests-in-windows-linux-unix-using-watir/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to run it on a linux box.  Xvfb doesn't exist in Windows or Mac